# ACF спрятать div c группой полей если значение пустое

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

В общем, создал группу с полями True\False, которые выводят или не выводят иконки, в зависимости от выбора чекбокса.
Всё отлично, иконки выводятся, но: если не выбрать ничего — всё равно выводится обёртка div.
Задача: чтобы оборачивающий поля div скрывался, если ни одно поле не выбрано.

```
<?php

    $icons = get_field('icons-group');  

    if( $icons ): ?>
    <div class="icons-group">
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <div class="icons">
            <?php if ( $icons['icon-1'] ): ?><span class="icon-item"><?php echo $icons['icon-1']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ( $icons['icon-2'] ): ?><span class="icon-item"><?php echo $icons['icon-2']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ( $icons['icon-3'] ): ?><span class="icon-item"><?php echo $icons['icon-3']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ( $icons['icon-4'] ): ?><span class="icon-item"><?php echo $icons['icon-4']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ( $icons['icon-5'] ): ?><span class="icon-item"><?php echo $icons['icon-5']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ( $icons['icon-6'] ): ?><span class="icon-item"><?php echo $icons['icon-6']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Есть еще вариант вывода через цикл в [документации](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/group/), попробуйте так.

```
<?php if( have_rows('hero') ): ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('hero') ): the_row(); 

        // Get sub field values.
        $image = get_sub_field('image');
        $link = get_sub_field('link');

        ?>
        <div id="hero">
            <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $image['url'] ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $image['alt'] ); ?>" />
            <div class="content">
                <?php the_sub_field('caption'); ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $link['url'] ); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr( $link['title'] ); ?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <style type="text/css">
            #hero {
                background-color: <?php the_sub_field('color'); ?>;
            }
        </style>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/410292)

Comment: Спасибо за логичное замечание, поправлю ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй ! empty ( $icons ), если не заработает, то пришли var_dump пустого $icons